# Getting an Array of Property Values Using Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'd like to extend each object in the array of objects below with an array of value* as seen below:

```
array = [object, object, object]

object = {key: array2, key2: value, key3: value}

array2 = [object2, object2]

object2 = {key: object3, key2: child, key3: object4}

object4 = {key: value, key2: value, key3: value*}
```

How do I write an underscore operation to extend the objects in the original array to include an array of value* as illustrated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using double `_.each` as a wrapper

```
_.each( array, function( item /* object */ )
{
    _.each( item.key /* array2 */, function( item /* object2 */ )
    {
        _.extend( item.key3 /* object4 */, {key3:5} )
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not bring the last key value pair to the front like I hoped. I've almost found it now and will publish my answer soon.

Comment: Actually I can't publish it because I changed my data structures so much to accomodate the change I was looking for that it no longer relates to the question . . .

Comment: Thanks for following up!